# Children's show featuring a skeleton host and possibly a talking wrench?

Tags: story-identification, tv

From what I remember, this show used to come on at 7pm on Saturdays. I would only watch it at every other weekend, so it most likely came on Saturday nights.  It was hosted by a skeleton who was either a puppet or possibly even CGI. The show included puzzles and a segment involving pipes and a talking wrench.

It's not "Tales From the Cryptkeeper" or "Funnybones." If someone could please tell me the name of this show, I'd be very grateful! It's been bugging me for a long time now.

Comment: Hi! welcome to SciFi.Stackexchange. According to this meta discussion http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/683/are-childrens-literature-and-cartoons-for-children-on-topic children's cartoons with no direct link to sci-fi/fantasy aren't considered on topic. If you gain over 20 reputation, you should be able to join our site's chat room to ask a question like this.

Comment: I'd say that a skeleton would at least put it on the fringe of fantasy... @Sarah if you can provide other information, like what year this would have been broadcast? was it story driven? etc...

Comment: @Sarah: Have I picked the right one? Wrong one? Or have you left and will not come back?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [Weinerville](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinerville)? It had a number of puppet characters, including a skeleton whose trademark was singing, "I'm Boney, I'm Boney, leave me aloney!"

Answer (score 1):

Was it [Skeleton Warriors](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108928/)?

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMU1_ctXthM)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_Warriors):

> The story takes place on the distant planet of Lumimaire. The conflict of the plot revolves around the need to control the Lightstar Crystal. This powerful crystal powers the great city of Luminicity. Baron Dark, the show's main villain, tried to steal the crystal in order to gain control over its incredible power. He only succeeded in obtaining half of the crystal, with the other half being obtained by Prince Lightstar.
>
> The half of the crystal that the Baron Dark managed to obtain turns him into a living skeleton. It also gives him the power to turn those with evil hearts into living skeletons for his army. Each episode involves Prince Lightstar, his siblings and Baron Dark attempting to obtain the other half of their respective crystals in order to gain control over the planet.

Answer (score 0):

[Crashbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crashbox)? It had a skeleton in it and it was kind of a sketch based show.

> The show takes place in the insides of a game computer where green game cartridges (which are sculpted out of clay) are created and loaded by rusty tin robots, occasionally with short sketches of them "repairing" damaged games. The format of each episode is The Electric Company-esque, with sketches not connecting nor following a sequential plot. Each half-hour episode consists of seven (occasionally eight) 2-to-5-minute educational games, covering subjects like history, math, spelling, and nature.

....

> Captain Bones - A pirate skeleton named Captain Bones has the viewers solve math problems, picture puzzles, and math riddles by having his bones form the equation or picture, often having the viewers move a limited number of his bones to pull it off. Throughout the game, Captain Bones will openly mock and demean the viewers using several pirate-esque insults, eventually becoming so irate that he blurts out the answer in rage.

Answer (score -1):

[OWL/TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OWL/TV), kids nature show, pretty sweet show.